# Type graph does not take parameters

Tags: java, jung

In order to create a multigraph I used the JUNG library but while coding i received this problem "type graph does not take parameters" and i can't find any solution to solve the problem in this code :

```
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.CircleLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.Layout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.SparseMultigraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.BasicVisualizationServer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.layout.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Simpleg {

Graph<Integer, String> g;
/** Creates a new instance of SimpleGraphView */
public Simpleg() {
    // Graph<V, E> where V is the type of the vertices and E is the type of the edges
    g = new SparseMultigraph<Integer, String>();
    // Add some vertices. From above we defined these to be type Integer.
    g.addVertex((Integer)1);
    g.addVertex((Integer)2);
    g.addVertex((Integer)3); 
    // Note that the default is for undirected edges, our Edges are Strings.
    g.addEdge("Edge-A", 1, 2); // Note that Java 1.5 auto-boxes primitives
    g.addEdge("Edge-B", 2, 3);  
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Simpleg sgv = new Simpleg(); //We create our graph in here
    // The Layout<V, E> is parameterized by the vertex and edge types
    Layout<Integer, String> layout = new CircleLayout(sgv.g);
    layout.setSize(new Dimension(300,300)); // sets the initial size of the layout space
    // The BasicVisualizationServer<V,E> is parameterized by the vertex and edge types
    BasicVisualizationServer<Integer,String> vv = new BasicVisualizationServer<Integer,String>(layout);
    vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,350)); //Sets the viewing area size

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Graph View");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(vv); 
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);       
}

}
```

Comment: Can you point the exact line where you get this error? Is this a runtime or a compilation error?

Comment: the error is in the line n°12 in this instruction :"Graph<Integer, String> g;"
and it's a runtime errror

Comment: Yes but is it an exception at runtime or a compilation error?

Comment: it an exception at runtime !!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the compiler - netbeans in my case - was pointing towards the wrong jar. I think Graph is available in JUNG 2.0

http://www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/JUNG2-Tutorial.pdf

My compiler was pointing at some lower version which I removed and added jung-api-2.0.1.jar